# Refresh content of view pager tab

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, hashmap, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have used tab layout with pager in android, where I am loading and displaying tabs dynamically based on the incoming network call result.

To display content as tab bar title and collection to particular tab, I have merged incoming response result as

`LinkedHashMap<String, List<Object>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();`

where, String will be tab title, and list of objects are the collection which is associated with that tab.

There is a delete button in each row for the collection, after deleting I am again calling same method to fetch updated content from server, due to which my pager is again starting from first tab (refreshing entire map and creating new one).

What if I want to refresh only particular tab, without refreshing entire map and saying adapter.notifyDataSetChange() method.

I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter to inflate tabs and fragment in pager.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the view pager can give you the flexibility you require out of the box.

It's usually designed for a fixed set of pages and if one needs changed it's assumed all will change ie. You change the entire collection of pages and not individual pages.

If you want to keep using the view pager then you could remember record page index you were on and after resetting the data on the adapter navigate to the recorded index however this could give a bad user experience on slower devices if you still have scrolling animations.

If you're open to alternatives then consider swapping your view pager and tabs for a recycler view.

The Recycler view adapter supports notify changes for specific indexes or ranges and supports additions/removals as well as updates.

You could displays the collection name and delete button in the recycler view cell. When the cell is tapped launch to either a screen or fragment that contains what the view pager fragment would have shown when the user tabbed a tab in your design.